# 1963 Astro Boy episode

Tags: episode-identification, astroboy

I saw this episode of Astro Boy in the '60s, so my memory is pretty vague. If I remember correctly, Astro Boy lands on - an asteroid? - some small space body, and finds the diary of a female astronaut who crash-landed there, was permanently marooned and eventually died there, not something one expected to see in a cartoon! It's haunted me ever since. I've looked at an episode guide but none of the titles seem familiar. I would appreciate any help in identifying this episode.   .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Episode 142: **[Minya's Star](http://tezukaosamu.net/en/anime/30.html)** from November 1965

> **Synopsis**
>
> ***There is a diary of a female soldier who never had the chance to return to Earth after her emergency landing on an ice
> planet.** Now Atom, who is riding on a sightseeing rocket, is forced to
> land on the same planet, and **finds the diary.** Then humans begin to
> quarrel shamefully over the two diamonds mentioned in the diary.*

Comment: This is it! Thanks for your help.